# angular http error Postman

Tags: angularjs

Using Postman, the restful query tool for Chrome, I can execute the following POST request with no error: (note - brackets are added here)

http://[myserver]/direct/session?_username=[usr]&_password=[pwd]

Why does the exact same query in my Angular factory always fail?

```
MyApp.factory('sessionFactory', function($http) {
var factory = {};

factory.authenticate = function(u,p) {
    var params = {
        _username:u,
        _password:p

    };
    var url = "[myserver]/direct/session?_username=[usr]&_password=[pwd]";
    $http.post(url)            
         .success(function (data, status, headers, config)    {
            console.log("Success " + status);
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Error " + status + config.toString() +  data.toString() +     headers.toString());
        });
};
return factory;
});
```

Firebug Console reports:

```
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://[myhost]/direct/session?_username=[usr]&_password=[pwd]"

Error 0[object Object]function (name) {
```

"use strict";

```
if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);

if (name) {
  return headersObj[lowercase(name)] || null;
}

return headersObj;
```

Comment: See if this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021442/how-postman-send-requests-ajax-same-origin-policy