# AngularJS and an external API - getting it to work like PostMan

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, web, postman

I've been trying to access the sqwiggle API inside my Angular app and was testing it using [Postman](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en&ei=zrj0UsqROKLNygPRg4KYAw&usg=AFQjCNHaecLwAKk91gpdCY_y1x_ViIrHwQ&sig2=SCupzp8fyscQNOgcA4yGeA&bvm=bv.60799247,d.bGQ). All seems to work fine. I define a Basic Auth header, do a GET request to the messages endpoint and I get a nice response. These are the request headers (from Postman):

```
Request URL:https://api.sqwiggle.com/messages
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
Authorization:Basic [secret]
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.sqwiggle.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.70 Safari/537.36
```

Now in my AngularJS app, I want to do the same:

```
$http.get('https://api.sqwiggle.com/messages', {
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic [secret]'
    }
}).success(function(e) {
    alert(e);
});
```

But this results in the following request headers:

```
Request URL:https://api.sqwiggle.com/messages
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:404 Not Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.sqwiggle.com
Origin:http://localhost:8888
Referer:http://localhost:8888/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53
```

Given the fact that Postman uses JS to get the data from the API, it should be possible in AngularJS too, or am I missing something here? Why is Angular transforming the GET in an OPTIONS request and why is it not adding the Authorization header?

Thanks for your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021442/how-postman-send-requests-ajax-same-origin-policy suggests Postman has Cross domain access because it's a Chrome app. My AngularJS app doesn't. That would explain why this doesn't work.

Comment: So What is the solution if I want to call the external API directly from Angualr JS.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this instead of using `$http.get`

```
$http({
    method: "get",
    url: "https://api.sqwiggle.com/messages",
    headers: {
        'Authorization' : 'Basic secret'
    }
}).success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```