# Cannot add custom header for $http.get in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

So, I am doing this request:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: query,
    headers: { 'api-key': 'test-api-key' }
});
```

In Chrome Developer Tools Network tab I can see the request being sent:

> ```
> Accept:*/*
> Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
> Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6
> Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, api-key
> Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
> Cache-Control:no-cache
> Connection:keep-alive
> Host:my-host.myhost.net
> Origin:http://localhost:24153
> Pragma:no-cache
> Referer:http://localhost:24153/
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36
> X-FirePHP-Version:0.0.6
> ```

**Q: What possible reasons may there be that the header is not added to the request?**

Answer (score 2):

You are making a cross-origin Ajax request with custom headers.

That makes it a complex request so the browser has to send [a pre-flight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) to get permission to make the cross-origin Ajax request.

If and when the server responds correctly to the OPTIONS request, the browser will make the GET request with the additional header you want.

Comment: Ok, got you, so enabling CORS, setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` on the server side should enable the server to respond to the OPTIONS request and the custom header should be added? But any ideas to why this request works using Postman?

Comment: Chrome packaged apps can have cross domain permissions. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021442/how-postman-send-requests-ajax-same-origin-policy) for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header and setting it to `*` did not help.

Comment: @Marcus — No, you need to respond with a `200 OK` that includes suitable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` (and probably `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`) headers. You're adding custom headers, allowing the origin alone is insufficient. There's an example in the MDN documentation linked to above.

Comment: Added `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to server response headers, issue remains.

Comment: Err. How about saying that the `api-key` header that you are adding is allowed?!

Comment: Tried: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With, content-type, api-key` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*` but issue remains. Maybe the CORS package will help...