# Javascript Post Body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, xmlhttprequest

i am trying to send a file over cross server via xmlhttprequest or jquery ajax, both seems to be sending the file to my dev server where i have a php to save the bit-stream to docx format.

The problem is when i am sending it to myclients server they get 0bytes. Strangely... when i use postman to send the file it works perfectly.
Below is my code to read and send the file.

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', my_file, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    // get binary data as a response
    var blob = this.response;
    var resume = new XMLHttpRequest();
    resume.open('POST', client_api, true);
    resume.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    resume.send(blob);

  }
};
xhr.send();
```

I am also able to fetch the data sent to my server. What my client's dev says is that i need to send the data stream in POST BODY... gets me totally confused at this point.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing some kind of cross domain restrictions. Postman can access any domain.

Read more [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) on how Chrome is handling cross origin request.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021442/how-postman-send-requests-ajax-same-origin-policy)