# Problems with sending POST request using Ajax jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a post request using ajax jquery but for some reason I am getting this annoying error jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 GET

```
https://moneywave.herokuapp.com/v1/merchant/?callback=jQuery3210014850591327852047_1514805273900&_=1514805273901 net::ERR_ABORTED
send @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
PostAction @ (index):75
onclick @ (index):45
(index):88 http status 404
```

What's strange is that when I am sending the POST Request from POSTMAN, I get the proper response code which is 400 BAD Request which is actually correct. However when I tried it from my code, it gives me a 404. What could I be doing wrong ?

```
 function PostAction() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url:"https://moneywave.herokuapp.com/v1/merchant/",
            headers: {
                'apiKey': '12893n3m3ki3',
                'secret':'jfjfjffjhfjfmk' },

            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
               // console.log("status",xhr.status);

            },
            complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                console.log("http status",xhr.status);
            }


        });
    }
```

POSTMAN POST REQUEST :

[image]

Comment: Could you check if the the api supports jsonp? (As I see it, in postman you don't have ?callback=... in the url, maybe the api does not support it.)

Comment: @RolandStarke;- The API accepts application/json as request type. However, I am confused why I have ?callback=.. in my request

Comment: @MonicaDas, the parameter is added automatically by jquery for the datatype jsonp that you specified. try using "json" as a datatype. see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: The browser prevents making requests and reading the response from a different origin. To overcome this issue the API must add jsonp support or allow CORS.

Comment: @RolandStarke:- This is what I get after changing datatype to json -Failed to load https://moneywave.herokuapp.com/v1/merchant/: Request header field secret is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: @MonicaDas Try Adding "crossDomain: true" in your ajax POST request, it will surely solve the issue of CORS headers.

Comment: According to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021442/how-postman-send-requests-ajax-same-origin-policy), Postman has browser's wildcard to cross-domain access unlike jquery/js from unauthorized domain. Also you can see that JSONP does not use POST but GET.