# Making unavailable my rest service out of my domain

Tags: node.js, authentication, cors

I have a webservice working on a domain say www.abc.com . I want to configure my server so that none of the request coming from another domain (except from www.abc.com) will be accepted. I should not use user authentication or anything related to token based authentication. So, the only option i can think is CORS but i do not exactly know how to use it. Any help would be great.

I am using nodejs and express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set a CORS header. Done.

To address your comment: Postman doesn't make Ajax requests, it makes requests. If you don't indicate in Postman that it's an Ajax request, it's just a standard client request.

See also [how Postman send requests? ajax, same origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16021442/438992) for some more details.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I haven't done anything CORS related in my application but by using postman, it is possible to get responses now

Comment: @OnurArı Updated.